# Finding the domain and Range of a piece wise Function,

Tags: functions, special-functions

Can someone explain to me how to find the domain and range of a piece wise function using this example? Thanks [image]

Comment: Let me ask you, what do you think the domain of this function is  ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "find" the domain of a function. The domain is a part of its definition. The range (or image, sometimes range also refers to the codomain then it is again part of the definition) of a function are all outputs of the function.

In your setup the domain could, e.g., be defined as $(0,\infty)$ and then the image is $\{x^{\frac{1}{3}}:x>2\} \cup (-1, 3]$.
The first set is from the first part of your piecewise definition and the second from the second part.